# Semantic markup for a forum's topic page

Tags: html, forum, semantic-markup, microdata

I have a large forum, you know, topics with *n* messages per topic. First message uses to have the main content of the topic, but sometimes some messages down are very useful too. One common case is when the first message is a question and then you get the answers.

Should the topic be an `article` element and the messages `article` elements inheriting from the topic article? In this case, should the first message appear in each message's page to be a reference? And then, how to deal with duplicated content?

An example:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
   <header>
      <h1 itemprop="name">My topic title</h1>
   </header>
   <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
      <div class="author" itemprop="author">Message author's name</div>
      <div class="message-body" itemprop="articleBody">
         message text bla bla
      </div>
      <p class="post-date" itemprop="dateModified" content="date">date</p>
   </article>
   <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
      <div class="author" itemprop="author">Message 2 author's name</div>
      <div class="message-body" itemprop="articleBody">
         message 2 text bla bla
      </div>
      <p class="post-date" itemprop="dateModified" content="date">date</p>
   </article>
   ... more messages ...
</article>
```

Is this a good practice for semantics, accessibility and SEO? Is there any better choice I can do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: @Will: Why would this be off-topic? It would be helpful to state the specific reason in the comment, otherwise OP has a hard time to improve the question. -- Do you mean the "and SEO" part? If yes, wouldn’t it be better to edit these two words out?

Comment: *"Is this a good practice for semantics, accessibility and SEO? Is there any better choice I can do?"* this is about how SEO works. Go read the [tag:seo] tag wiki.

Comment: @Will: Two of the three aspects are on-topic (semantic markup, accessibility). The third aspect (SEO) isn’t even essential to the question, and easy to edit out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each post should be an `article`. Nothing else should be an `article`. So the title of the thread should be part of the first post, not of a container.

You can either nest the replies in the first post, or have all posts on the same level. [HTML 5.2 about `article`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#the-article-element):

> When `article` elements are nested, the inner `article` elements represent articles that are in principle related to the contents of the outer article.

For the author pane, you could use the `footer` element.

Instead of using Schema.org’s `Article` type, you might want to use the more specific [`DiscussionForumPosting`](http://schema.org/DiscussionForumPosting) type (which inherits from `Article`).

#### Nested

```
<article>
  <h2>My topic title</h2>
  <footer>…</footer>
  <div>…</div>

  <article>
    <h3>Reply: My topic title</h3>
    <footer>…</footer>
    <div>…</div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h3>Reply: My topic title</h3>
    <footer>…</footer>
    <div>…</div>
  </article>

</article>
```

#### Same level

```
<article>
  <h2>My topic title</h2>
  <footer>…</footer>
  <div>…</div>
</article>

<article>
  <h2>Reply: My topic title</h2>
  <footer>…</footer>
  <div>…</div>
</article>

<article>
  <h2>Reply: My topic title</h2>
  <footer>…</footer>
  <div>…</div>
</article>
```